# How can I set the scroll area and origin on a UserControl with AutoScroll?

Tags: winforms, user-controls, scroll, autoscroll

:) My question is quite a mouthful.

This is a WinForms question :

I'm making a UserControl where the mouse wheel is used for zooming and the content would be drawn using GDI+.
After I activate AutoScroll, how can I set the area size and origin of the scroll view ?

Thank in advance for any help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AutoScrollMinSize.